# How to check if Clipboard contains Specific Criteria

Tags: vb.net, windows, forms

Using Vb.net 2015, Windows Forms Application.
I have one Form with two textbox's on it, nothing else.
On Form Load I would like to check if the Clipboard Contains Text.
If the Clipboard does contain Text then if 'Criteria" is met past the text into textbox 1.

- Criteria - "INC" + more than 3 numbers, or
- "ADR" + More than 3 numbers.

If the above = True then paste the text into Textbox1. 
If the criteria is not met, do nothing.

Then I would like to use this same Criteria later in the application as reference True or False.

Any Assistance is appreciated.

Comment: That's a nice requirement.  What have you done to accomplish this?  What is it doing?  Why isn't it doing what you need?

Comment: Which part are you stick on - that seems like a clear task list except for what kicks it off

Comment: To Answer both your questions, thank you.

Comment: Currently the program does nothing. I would like it to check the clipboard for the above mentioned criteria on Form Load event. Then as I add other items to the form have it keep any eye for the clipboard to contain text that is also in the same criteria and if it is then also paste the text into the textbox. The user should not have to perform any actions to have this done, except use the application. I found some information on an MSDN website: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2ft7ez4.aspx. However I’m not sure this would be considered “special formatting”? Thank you again,